# Determining which of the following groups are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I am trying to solve the below problem.

> Below are several examples of groups. Among these, determine which are isomorphic to each other or to subgroups of other groups.
>
> 1. The trivial group $\{e\}$.
> 2. Number systems with addition: $\left(\mathbb{Z}, +\right)$, $\left(\mathbb{Q}, +\right)$, $\left(\mathbb{R}, +\right)$, $\left(\mathbb{C}, +\right)$.
> 3. $\{0,1\}$ with addition mod 2; $\{\pm 1\}$ with multiplication.
> 4. $\mathbb{Z}/n = \{0,1, \ldots, n-1\}$ with addition mod $n$ and $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, which is the set $[0,1)$ with the addition law $(a,b) \mapsto$ $a+b$ if $a + b < 1$ and $a + b - 1$ otherwise.
> 5. Non-zero numbers with multiplication: $\mathbb{Q}^{\star}$, $\mathbb{R}^{\star}$, $\mathbb{C}^{\star}$, and the unit circle $S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}^{\star}$.
> 6. Permutations of a set $A$, $\mathrm{Perm}(A)$, and symmetric group on $n$ letters $S_n$.
> 7. $\mathrm{GL}_n (F)$ and $\mathrm{SL}_n (F)$ for some field $F$.
> 8. Direct products and direct sums of finitely or infinitely many groups.

Here is my attempt. I am focusing more on finding the isomorphisms and understanding them intuitively than directly proving them, which I'm going to do later on, but don't have too much trouble with.

As $\mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Z}$ as sets, $\left(\mathbb{Z}, +\right) \cong \left(\mathbb{Q}, +\right)$. Since there exists a natural embedding $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ sending $x \mapsto x + 0i$, we can identify $\left(\mathbb{R}, +\right)$ with a subgroup of $\left(\mathbb{C}, +\right)$, namely the real axis under addition. Similarly, we can embed $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, so we can identify $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ with a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$.

We can proceed exactly analagously for multiplication. Namely, we can identify $\mathbb{Q}^{\star}$ with a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^{\star}$, $\mathbb{R}^{\star}$ with a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{\star}$, and $S^1$ with a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{\star}$.

Permutations of the set $A = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ and $S_n$ are surely isomorphism, and $\mathrm{SL}_n (F)$ can be identified with a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n (F)$.

Direct sums can be identified with a subgroups of direct products, holding the groups $G_i$ fixed.

---

I'm surely missing a few. There is a hint to consider $\mathbb{Z}/n$, $\mathbb{C}^{\star}$, and $GL_2 (\mathbb{R})$, but I can't think of any.

Comment: If $A \simeq B$ as sets, it is not necessarily true that $(A, +) \simeq (B, +)$.

Comment: The simplest example is $\text{Klein's four group} \not \simeq \text{Cyclic four group}$.

Comment: The interesting thing is, direct sums are isomorphic to direct products with finitely many groups :P

Comment: $(\mathbb Z,+)$ and $(\mathbb Q,+)$ are not isomorphic as groups. The easiest way to see this is to note that for any $a\in\mathbb Q$, there exists $b\in\mathbb Q$ such that $b+b=a$, but that's not true in $\mathbb Z$, so there's no homomorphism from $\mathbb Q$ into $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Perhaps you should also prove that $S^1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and that $\mathbb{R}^*$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^*$ (this is not because one is a proper subgroup of the other). Moreover, $\mathbb{Z}/n$ can be embedded in to $\mathbb{C}^*$ and $\mathbb{C}^*$ embeds into $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ (this is one way to define complex numbers).

Comment: In 3 they are. In 6 if and only if $card(A)=n$.

Comment: Also $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925706/is-it-true-that-group-of-real-numbers-under-addition-isomorphic-to-group-of-comp

Comment: @Trebor, what do you mean by "$A \simeq B$ as sets"?

Comment: @CAB It's just what the OP means by $A\cong B$ I assume. There exists an isomorphism between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Don't forget $S_3 \cong \operatorname{GL}_2(2) = \operatorname{SL}_2(2)$, and $\operatorname{SL}_4(2)$ is isomorphic to $A_8$ which is a subgroup of $S_8$ (this question taken literally is completely ridiculous for a beginner).

Comment: I think these are too many questions packed in a single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarize some of the non-trivial (non)isomorphisms:

- $(\mathbb{Z},+)\not\cong(\mathbb{Q},+)$, since the former is cyclic and the latter not even finitely generated.
- $(\mathbb{Q},+)\not\cong(\mathbb{R},+)$, since the cardinality is different.
- $(\mathbb{R},+)\cong(\mathbb{C},+)$, since those are $\mathbb{Q}$-vectorspaces of the same dimension (assuming axiom of choice).
- $\mathbb{Z}^*\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{Z}^*=\{1,-1\}$ denotes the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}$.
- $\mathbb{Q}^*\cong\mathbb{Z}^*\times\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}$ via the prime factorization $\pm 2^{a_1}3^{a_2}5^{a_3}\ldots\mapsto (\pm1,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$.
- $\mathbb{R}^*\not\cong\mathbb{C}^*$, since the latter has elements of order $3$ (roots of unity).
- $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong S^1$ by the homomorphism $r\mapsto e^{2\pi r}$ with kernel $\mathbb{Z}$.
- $\mathrm{SL}_n(F)\not\cong \mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ unless $|F|=2$. Almost always, $SL_n(F)$ is perfect and $GL_n(F)$ is not.
- $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)\cong\mathrm{GL}_m(F')$ if and only if $n=m$ and $F\cong F'$. See [Is there a simple way of proving that $\text{GL}_n(R) \not\cong \text{GL}_m(R)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686695/is-there-a-simple-way-of-proving-that-textgl-nr-not-cong-textgl-mr).

Comment: Don't forget $\mathbb{Q}^\times\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\oplus \bigoplus_n \mathbb Z$, and if $F$ has no non-trivial $n$th roots of unity, $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)\cong \mathrm{SL}_n(F)\times F^\times$.